# non-www to www on https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I had some trouble redirecting http to https. A friend helped me to find a solution, but there are still some troubles.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?thevideocards\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thevideocards.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This redirects http to https, http to https://www but does not https://example to https://www.example. Anybody any idea what should change to force ALL traffic to https://www.example.com ?

Comment: Most browsers by default just remove the www (but its still there)

Comment: well, it stays there if you go to https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand what the code you're writing means - otherwise, who knows what backdoors someone is persuading you to add.

Let's break down what you have:

```
# Turn on Apache's "Rewrite Engine"; this is the module that processes the next few lines
RewriteEngine On 

# Condition (for following rule): match only if the connection is on port 80
# Port 80 is (by convention) used for plain-text HTTP traffic
# An alternative to this would be to check for a secure connection directly:
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

# Condition (for following rule): match only if the HTTP Host header matches a regex
# The (www\.)? means that prefix is optional, 
#  so it will match both www.thevideocards.com and thevideocards.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?thevideocards\.com

# Rule (if the above two conditions also match):
# ^(.*)$ - Match any URL, and capture as $1
# https://www.thevideocards.com/$1 - Generate the replacement URL based on the captured part
# [R] - Send redirect response to browser, rather than processing internally
# [L] - Don't process any more rewrite rules for this request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thevideocards.com/$1 [R,L]
```

From the above, you should be able to create your own rule for the case you want:

- Condition: host matches without the `www.`
- Rule: redirect everything to the same URL with `https://www.` on the front

(Alternatively, spend 10 minutes searching and you'll probably find about a million pages talking about how to do this; but again, if you don't know what they do, how will you know which one to trust?)

Comment: You are correct. There are many, many pages that explain and give example what to do. I followed some, but ran into a problem where the redirect resulted in 404 as the address was https://www.example.com/example.com/page.php. I wish I would spent 10 minutes searching how to avoid this. It was hours with different code and looking into what went wrong. Of course, part of it is that I am not a programmer, so have no idea what it means. The solution I put was the only one that worked, not perfectly, but worked. Thank you. I will look into your explanation.

Comment: @MartinP A lot of people seem to think programming will come easily; imagine you were facing a problem with your car: you can buy a manual, follow it blindly, and wreck your engine; you can spend time understanding what's going on, doing your homework week after week; or you can pay a mechanic who has already spent that time. The same is true here: once you've spent hours learning the basic principles, it will take you 10 minutes to solve this particular problem; but you have to learn those principles first - or decide you're not that interested, and pay someone who already has.